# Is constantly instantiating new web workers bad?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, web-worker

I am currently doing large file uploads using web workers. I have a method that breaks the file into 5MB+ blobs, calculates a checksum(using a webworker) for the blob, and uploads that blob(using another webworker) to a special server that will reassemble the parts.

THE question I have is whether or not calling new Worker() and closing it a bunch of times a bad practice. For example, say i have a 1GB file being uploaded, chopped into 5MB blobs, I will have instantiated and closed 400 workers(200 for checksum and 200 for upload). Does it make more sense to just instantiate a single worker and let it do the necessary the work?

Comment: What is your advantage of breaking it into 5mb chunks initially?

Comment: Correction, the file isn't chunked into 5MB initially. I calculate a part count based on file size / 5MB and i basically grab a slice of the file for a given part number.

Comment: Ok. Why do you do that?

Comment: Large file uploads tend to be unreliable, so breaking the file into parts and uploading the parts in smaller batches makes more sense. gives us some added ability to retry upload for a given part.

Comment: Have you profiled CPU/memory when instantiating that many workers?

Comment: Can't you just [resume](http://www.resumablejs.com/) [the upload](https://tus.io/demo.html) instead of chunking it? Although maybe a small amount of chunking might speed it up, not sure. I'd expect your network to be saturated either way.

Comment: I feel this question is a bit too broad for me to give a proper answer (too many parts in it). But for the multiple WebWorkers part, if they're instantiated in parrallel, you can only run  *n <= [`navigator.hardwareConcurrency`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorConcurrentHardware/hardwareConcurrency)* at the same time. All others's execution will be delayed, which might give slower results than using the single main thread. Now if you run them sequentially in this limit, there shouldn't be much difference between creating and closing instances vs a single instance.

Comment: @Kaiido your comment is what I was more looking to towards as an answer. I am actually currently limiting them into a pool based on hardwareConcurrency, so at any given time, I have active workers <= hardwareConcurrency. The workers in the active pool get removed once their work is complete, and close themselves when done.

Comment: @JoshBeam I profiled based on hardwareConcurrency limit, given an 1G upload for the work i was doing and didn't see anything glaring, heap size fluctated as expected when reading in ArrayBuffers and then those buffers getting released, and cpu seemed stable, no spikes.

Comment: Then I think the little memory impact each new Worker instance will create is nothing compared to the whole data you do treat. But beware, your uploading part might also need to be made sequentially, it is implementation dependent, but some browsers won't allow too many parallel requests. Also, from own tests and without any reliable source, I think browsers will keep in memory what's to be sent to the server, so if the browser do accepts all the requests to be made in parallel, it might suck a lot of memory.

Comment: @mpen The chunking is done for a specific workflow, where we are being provided presigned s3 urls for the parts to go to, which will all be different.  ie (file part 1 is going to different upload url then file part 2). actually hadn't looked at tus.io before, definitely will check it out. not sure if it will fit my current use case due to the different urls for each chunk.

Comment: Ah. Well I can't answer your original question, I think you'd have to do some performance testing. My gut says that there's a non-0 cost to instantiating a worker though so it'd be better to create a pool of ~8 workers or however many CPU cores you have and re-use them. I don't think you're going to squeeze out any extra performance by trying to hash 200 chunks in parallel; I'd think a net loss due to the extra context switching. Especially if you don't begin the upload until the hash is complete, it'd be in your interest to complete the hashes faster.